# Spectroscopy on plant leafs

Tags: botany, light, methods, measurement, spectroscopy

I'm trying to do spectroscopy readings on plants where I shoot electromagnetic waves and look at their signature/profile. 
I want to be able to do this at a distance, in the field and on live plants so that I can modify my rig later to automatically do this on multiple plants daily.

I have no background in spectroscopy, but I heard that waves directed  through leaves can then be received on the other end using something like waveguide spectroscopy. I do not know the frequency range I should be looking at and was wondering how can I identify the range of interest for my plants.
Let's say I want to approximate the chlorophyll content in leaves and see if the leaf is healthy or not and look at its change daily. Some references to learn about this would be very helpful. Thanks!